# Get digest value of SOAP Envelope XML (Web Services Security:SOAP Message Security 1.1)

Tags: c#, soap, hash, service, soapui

I am trying to implement the signing of  this SOAP-envelope document in C# with binary security token and X509 certificate to consume a service. This XML must comply with Web Services Security:SOAP Message Security 1.1(WS-Security 2004). I was able to properly do it in SOAPUI as well as in C# using Chilkat. Now I am trying to redo it manually but I cant get the same digest values.

If I understood correctly the procedure is:
A) Canonicalize the whole XML. In this case is canonicalized with xml-exc-c14n.

B) Digest the soapenv:Body element as it is indicated in the reference URI with the ID (#id-5157A8F91DFED0BF1516369837630694) with SHA-256 and obtain the base 64 of the hash.

But still not able to get the same hash (In this case, the correct value is **sLXr8sDC07k7ln7y7kZ1SwCw5BU4z7o9jGA77PfjvHs** while i get wrong SR0QiRYmF21SR2WG/v10zqa9vsSqNUi6p3jN8BQ/uT0=)

I will include the code I use for manual calculation, the starting XML , the final XML and the code I am using to get the digest value. I would like to know how to get the proper digestValues.

------------------------FINAL XML---------------------------------------------------------

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:loc="http://administracion.gob.es/punto-unico-notificaciones/localiza" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-5157A8F91DFED0BF1516369837631526">
                <wsu:Created>2022-03-04T13:48:25Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2022-03-04T13:53:25Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-5157A8F91DFED0BF1516369837630331">..BinarySecurityTokenValue...</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-5157A8F91DFED0BF1516369837631235">
  <ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsa loc soapenv"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <ds:Reference URI="#id-5157A8F91DFED0BF1516369837630694">
      <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="loc"/></ds:Transform>
      </ds:Transforms>
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <ds:DigestValue>sLXr8sDC07k7ln7y7kZ1SwCw5BU4z7o9jGA77PfjvHs=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:SignatureValue>WH7BHRTk2X5q8oHVroXkhcCUEL/OEM+T/OfNjhWCrZ9UuFH6QSs6kWJ3MPmpbQ5IdAHD2fJJB9d9nH/5fAaQiez/VUVOK9xFOceNeLlz8uuO1AcSNEz5Bq+fB1dswTrxSei+1/df7byD/bYREt0l8In4Y0FfZ84CSEiSblZqkJS5b9W8P/mLlS2qA9CelahD+b3YCFa3qdWEosC467XD1LVNBRMBBUhvk/kPgmzsRO4HBl6u2y9xi+Xpyun70TFJ3WgxKIo+2seTA+o667iKfpRt2HICDOCGLWfVGWwMSAb8svhPSh18YMq2NOUyfxjmlkKx2lPV8UVOeZAaKuXikQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
  <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-5157A8F91DFED0BF1516369837630652"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-5157A8F91DFED0BF1516369837630663">
    <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-5157A8F91DFED0BF1516369837630331" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
  </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature></wsse:Security>
        <wsa:Action>https://administracionelectronica.gob.es/notifica/ws/lema/Localiza</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>uuid:4251a8a3-8e14-4218-844e-c9854a3fcff5</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:To>https://se-dehuws.redsara.es/ws/v2/lema</wsa:To>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-5157A8F91DFED0BF1516369837630694" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <loc:Localiza>
            <loc:nifTitular>A</loc:nifTitular>
            <loc:nifDestintario>A</loc:nifDestintario>
            <loc:opcionesLocaliza>
                <loc:opcion tipo="dehu.paginador.pagina">1</loc:opcion>
            </loc:opcionesLocaliza>
        </loc:Localiza>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

--------------------------START XML-------------------------------------------------------------

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:loc="http://administracion.gob.es/punto-unico-notificaciones/localiza">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <loc:Localiza>
         <loc:nifTitular>B87222014</loc:nifTitular>
         <loc:nifDestintario>B87222014</loc:nifDestintario>
         <loc:opcionesLocaliza>
           <loc:opcion tipo="dehu.paginador.pagina">1</loc:opcion>
         </loc:opcionesLocaliza>
      </loc:Localiza>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

---------------------------------C# CODE---------------------------------------------------------

```
string canon = CanonicalizeDsig(File.ReadAllText(@"PATHTOXMLFILE"));

XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
x.LoadXml(canon);
XmlNodeList j = x.GetElementsByTagName("soapenv:Body");
resultado1 = getDigest(j[0].OuterXml);

     string getDigest(string mesg)
            {
                SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create();
                byte[] mesgBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mesg);
               byte[] hash =  sha256Hash.ComputeHash(mesgBytes);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
            }

            string CanonicalizeDsig(string input)
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
                try
                {
                    doc.LoadXml(input);
                    XmlDsigExcC14NTransform trans = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
                    trans.LoadInput(doc);
                    String c14NInput = new StreamReader((Stream)trans.GetOutput(typeof(Stream))).ReadToEnd();

                    return c14NInput;


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return String.Empty;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Hi sls i am. Also facing the issue. Did u find any solution?

Comment: Ey mavrav. Sorry but I couldn't find a proper way without Chilkat. Let me know if you find  a way.

Answer (score 1):

The signature covers a node with Id="id-5157A8F91DFED0BF1516369837630694", see ds:Reference element:

```
<ds:Reference URI="#id-5157A8F91DFED0BF1516369837630694">
  <ds:Transforms>
    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="loc"/></ds:Transform>
  </ds:Transforms>
  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
  <ds:DigestValue>sLXr8sDC07k7ln7y7kZ1SwCw5BU4z7o9jGA77PfjvHs=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
```

While the provided document does not contain a node with that Id at all.
So either you need to include the Id to the parent element of the SOAP envelope, or (a better way) is to implement an enveloped signature format, by de-referencing the enveloping XML with a URI="" (empty URI) and adding an enveloped-signature transform before the canonicalization. E.g.:

```
<dsig:Reference URI="">
    <dsig:Transforms xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    </dsig:Transforms>
    <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
    <dsig:DigestValue>*some value*</dsig:DigestValue>
</dsig:Reference>
```

For more information about the de-reference model and enveloped-signatures please see [XMLDSig](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-EnvelopedSignature) specification.